# How do you set the text direction of a website's title?

Tags: javascript, html, arabic, direction, lang

I have a site that needs to display the title in the correct direction.

I have have tried adding dir="rtl" to the html, head and title tags but nothing seems to take affect.

On the English version I have "Select a service:"
On the Arabic version I have "اختر خدمة:" but I want ":اختر خدمة" (just the colon needs to change)

I need a solution that works with dynamic content. A JavaScript function that gets the exact same result as dir="rtl" would work for me if one exists?

Answer (score 0):

Start your title text with `&#x202b;` followed by your title, this will align title to `rtl`

For more information and reference please refer the link [Check out this link](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/)

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>&#x202b; Your Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using dir="auto".

> auto -> which lets the user agent decide. It uses a basic algorithm as
>   it parses the characters inside the element until it finds a character
>   with a strong directionality, then applies that directionality to the
>   whole element.

As quoted in MDN docs,
[dir attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir)